# Split a string field into an array in jq?

Tags: json, jq

I have a JSON array returned from curl that looks like this:

```
[
 {
   "title": "Some Title",
   "tags":"tagA tag-B tagC"
 },
 {
   "title": "Some Title 2",
   "tags":"tagA tagC"
 },
 ...
]
```

I'd like to convert it to...

```
[
 {
   "title": "Some Title",
   "tags":["tagA",
           "tag-B",
           "tagC"]
 },
 {
   "title": "Some Title 2",
   "tags":["tagA", 
           "tagC"]
 },
 ...
]
```

So far I have:

`(map(select(.tags!=null)) | map(.tags | split(" "))) as $tags | $tags`

and that appears to give me something like:

```
     [
      [
       "tagA",
       "tag-B",
       "tagC"
      ],
      [
       "tagA", 
       "tagC"
      ]
     ]
```

But I don't seem to be able to weave that back into an output that would give me `.tags` as an array in the original objects with the original values...

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You're making it a lot more complicated than it is.  Just use `map()` and `|=`:

```bash
jq 'map(.tags |= split(" "))' file.json
```

**Edit:**

If you want to handle entries without `tags`:

```
jq 'map(try(.tags |= split(" ")))' file.json
```

Alternatively, if you want to keep unchanged all entries without `tags`:

```
jq 'map(try(.tags |= split(" ")) // .)' file.json
```

Result:

```json
[
  {
    "tags": [
      "tagA",
      "tag-B",
      "tagC"
    ],
    "title": "Some Title"
  },
  {
    "tags": [
      "tagA",
      "tagC"
    ],
    "title": "Some Title 2"
  }
]
```

Comment: Okay I still needed to filter out the `null`s first with 'map(select.tags!=null))' with my dataset, but you are correct that does work.

Comment: @leeand00 Edited.

Comment: @SatōKatsura Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can attempt this is `sed` as follows:

The code below is using GNU version of sed (although it can be portably written in POSIX-compatible as well)

```
sed -e '
   /[{]/,/[}]/!b
   /"tags":/!b

   h;s/"tags":/&\n/;s/\n.*/ /;s/./ /g;x

   s/"tags":/&\n/
   :a
   s/\(\n.*\)\([^"]\) \([^"]\)/\1\2","\3/;ta

   y/\n/[/;s/$/]/;G

   :b
   s/","\(.*\)\(\n.*\)/",\2"\1\2/;tb
   s/\(.*\)\n.*/\1/

' yourjsonfile
```

---

### Working

1. We select the range as `{` to the next `}` lines.
2. Zoom in on `"tags"` line in the range selected.
3. Compute the nesting spaces for the given tag and store it in hold.
4. Double quote the tag data in a loop `:a`
5. Insert the nesting spaces after the `,` in a loop `:b`
6. Remove everything after the last newline in the pattern space & print.

---

### Results

```
[
 {
   "title": "Some Title",
   "tags":["tagA",
           "tag-B",
           "tagC"]
 },
 {
   "title": "Some Title 2",
   "tags":["tagA",
           "tagC"]
 },
 ...
]
```

Comment: OP specifically asks for jq.

Comment: While this answer is not per OP's original request, and I really would avoid using sed for this job if at all possible, I don't think this deserves a down-vote. For those in a tight spot, POSIX options may be their only option and I see this answer as having value for that reason alone. That said, your sed skills are scary good.

Comment: I agree. Also, jq isn't available everywhere, centos for example isn't providing it and you have to install epel to get it. In a CI deployment knowing how to do stuff with base tools without having to install stuff is a must have skill.